# How to insert key, value pair of object to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this:

```
var obj = {
   0: {...},
   1: {...},
   2: {...}, 
   3: {...},
   4: {...}
}
```

And then I have an if statement with some logic to see which values I want in each key. If found some values I want to insert that into an array but with the same key/value as the object, like this:

```
var array = [ 1: {...}, 3: {...}, 4:{...} ];
```

My problem is when I am creating the array and inserting the values and when I see in development tools in Chrome for example the console it stays always like this:

```
var array = [ 0: {...}, 1: {...}, 2:{...} ];
```

Even if the values are what I want the keys always start with 0. I am just doing an 'if' and then push that into my array.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  if(key == obj.someValue){
      arr.push(value);   
   }
}
```

This is my logic. Someone can help me?

Comment: Please post all your *relevant* code including the  if statement and its logic

Comment: Show us the code which inserts your values.

Comment: If your object keys are just sequential numbers, use an array. Please provide more context on why you want/need to 1-index the array, which is unusual. If you really must do this, prepend `null`. `[null].concat(Object.values(yourSequentiallyKeyedObJ))`.

Comment: I edited my logic

Comment: You'd just use `arr[key] = value` instead of `arr.push(…)`? But really, don't do that, arrays are good for sequential values. At least make an `else { arr[key] = undefined; }` or so.

Comment: So what should i do instead?

Comment: @FredericoGomes Please show us your actual code so that we can suggest an appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Array push() will create sequentially numbered keys. If there is a need for having the same key into the new array you can use

```
if(key == obj.someValue){
   arr[key] = value;   
}
```

To retrieve both key and value from new array, use for-in

```
for (key in arr) {
   console.log(key); //key
   console.log(arr[key]); //value
}
```